# Google Tag Manager and $ (JQuery) undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Google Tag Manager. If I hit `F12` and enter `jQuery`, jQuery is defined and working. However, `$` is not. It appears that the Tag Manager is redefining $.

Any ideas please?

Here's a cut down example.

```
 <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <head>
                        <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
                        <script>
                            (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
                                w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
                                    'gtm.start':
                                        new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
                                }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                                    j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
                                        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
                            })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-ABCDEFG');
                        </script>
                        <!-- END OF Google Tag Manager script -->
                        <title></title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                         <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-ABCDEFG"></iframe></noscript>
       
                        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
                    </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: `<script>$ = jQuery</script`

Answer (score 1):

Order in imports count, as the script run as soon as it's `<scrit>` element is loaded.

one solution is to move your `gtm` script from the head to after Jquery.

Second solution is to add `defer` attribute to the `gmt` script. Defer will force the script to wait the page to load before starting the execution